# Embedding Jetty 9 using ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets, jetty-9

I'm trying to upgrade from Jetty 7 to Jetty 9 using the samples here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html#d0e18177

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler context=new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
HttpServlet servlet=new TestServlet();
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), "/*");
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
```

However, it dies at runtime:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:304)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:103)
```

The servlet in the sample is a simple hello world sample.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example using Jetty9 Embedded/Servlets using a supplied Jetty 'DefaultServlet' class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Server server = new Server(8080);
  ServletContextHandler context=new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
  context.setContextPath("/");
  DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
  ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", defaultServlet);
context.addServlet(holderPwd, "/*");
  server.setHandler(context);
  server.start();
  server.join();
}
```

Output:

> 2014-04-08 10:04:18.173:INFO::main: Logging initialized @132ms
>   2014-04-08 10:04:18.243:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.3.v20140225
>   2014-04-08 10:04:18.282:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@52e21a17{/,null,AVAILABLE}
>   2014-04-08 10:04:18.298:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@7388665b{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
>   2014-04-08 10:04:18.298:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @259ms

Comment: I was deliberately instantiating the class for my current use case. I have this working with jetty 7, but can't get it to run in jetty 8 and above.

Comment: Updated example to instantiate DefaultServlet class directly. Not able to reproduce original problem. Might be additional capability required in the 'TestServlet' class on Jetty9. A lot appears to have changed for embedded servlets in Jetty9.

Comment: Without the import statements the sample is useless.